# Backend tests only runs on 1 out of 3 TeamCity build agents. Error: 'Unable to find testhost.dll. Please publish your test project and retry.'

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, nunit, teamcity

All backendtests works fine locally and on one of the TeamCity agents, but always fails when another TeamCity agent tries to run them.

I logged onto all agents, and can't find any differences between them.
Other issues I have found with 'Unable to find testhost.dll' error, have been solved with referencing `Microsoft.Net.Test.SDK`, but that doesn't work.

In the logs for the agent working:

```
[10:52:07][vstest] Starting test execution, please wait...
[10:52:09][vstest] NUnit Adapter 3.13.0.0: Test execution started
```

In the logs for one of the agents not working:

```
[12:27:56][vstest] Starting test execution, please wait...
[12:27:57][vstest] Unable to find D:\TeamCity\BuildAgent5\work\b75e42d21fae163\tests\UnitTests\bin\Release\netcoreapp2.2\testhost.dll. Please publish your test project and retry.
[12:27:57][vstest] Test Run Aborted.
```

Everything before this looks simular. I think the agents that are not working can't fint NUnit Adapter, but I have no idea why. I checked the folder over and all agents had both `NUnit3.TestAdapter.dll` and `NUnit3.TestAdapter.pbd` in the same versions.